# how to get html content from XML using SAX parser in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sax

i tried using CDATA in the xml i worked on most of the answers given in stackoverflow but i could not find the answer.

When CDATA is included, parser is not at all recognizing the data.

Is this any problem with android or are there any other parsers to parse? I tried using DOM, but since my xml file is too large DOM is unable to handle it. Please suggest me any working parser or a way to parse the html content.. Thank you..

Comment: "since my xml file is too large DOM is unable to handle it" As this is targetting a mobile platform, is there a better way which maybe doesn't involve XML?

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with CDATA in the xml, it happens for Android < 2.2 because it uses an ancient and buggy version of Xerces (I think it was Xerces that Android is using). Try to build your project for 2.2 and give it a try.

If you can't use 2.2 - there is a manual workaround that I was able to pull off. Unfortunately, I don't have the code for it in handy at the moment, sorry about that :(